# Why do I keep Getting ELIF Invalid Syntax Error?

Tags: python

Getting an ELIF syntax error, I'm new to python and i have no idea why I'm I getting this error

```
print("Résolution de l'équation du second degré : ax² + bx + c = 0")
chaineA= input("Coefficient de a ?: ")
a= float(chaineA)
chaineB= input("Coefficient de b ?: ")
b= float(chaineB)
chaineC= input("Coefficient de c ?: ")
c= float(chaineC)
delta=((b**2)-(4*a*b))
solut1= (-b + (delta**0.5)/(2*a))
solut2= (-b - (delta**0.5)/(2*a))
solut3= (-b/2*a)

if delta >= 0.0:
    print("Deux solutions: ")
    print("x1 =" , solut1)
    print("x2 =" , solut2)
elif delta = 0.0:
    print("Une solution")
    print("x =" , solut3)
elif delta <= 0.0:
    print("Pas de solution")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: should be `elif delta == 0.0` (note the double `==` for comparison).

Comment: your algorithm has a faute de principe

Comment: @zipen check my remarks regarding the algorithm in my answer. and try to understand why u had a mistake other than the syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("Résolution de l'équation du second degré : ax² + bx + c = 0")
chaineA= input("Coefficient de a ?: ")
a= float(chaineA)
chaineB= input("Coefficient de b ?: ")
b= float(chaineB)
chaineC= input("Coefficient de c ?: ")
c= float(chaineC)
delta=((b**2)-(4*a*b))
solut1= (-b + (delta**0.5)/(2*a))
solut2= (-b - (delta**0.5)/(2*a))
solut3= (-b/2*a)

if delta >= 0.0: # here it should be > only
    print("Deux solutions: ")
    print("x1 =" , solut1)
    print("x2 =" , solut2)
elif delta = 0.0: # first error here it should be elif delta == 0:
    print("Une solution")
    print("x =" , solut3)
else: #this could be made else. no need to put a condition.
    print("Pas de solution")
```

Answer (score 1):

you have used single `=` instead of `==`.

```
elif delta == 0.0:
```

Answer (score 1):

By only using one = in your elif it thinks you are trying to assign 0.0 to delta. It should be:

```
elif delta == 0.0
```

This will compare delta to 0.0 and if they are the same run your code in the elif.